# Launchd script's output not being logged to system.log

Tags: launchd, logs

Sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello?"
... (other things)
```

When run via launchd, it definitely runs (the other things are being done) but nothing shows up in system.log. I'm running OS 10.9.

I tried replacing that line with

```
syslog -s "HELLO?"
```

but that also shows nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the command `logger`instead.
For example `logger "test"` will result in
`Nov  7 17:37:20 bounty.local napcae[82311]: test`
in the file `/var/log/system.log`.

Altough you can use it, I'd recommend to write to your own log file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea why exactly syslog didn't work?

Comment: No, I tried it too. But I did not further inspect it so I can't tell you why it did not work.